# QTP recognising a JavaEdit object but not able to set a value when running the script

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have written a simple script to log into a Java app where it fills in username and password, and then clicks on the "Connect" button".

```
Set UVC = JavaDialog("UVC")
wait(20)
If UVC.Exist Then
    UVC.JavaEdit("JTextField").Set "admin"
    wait(2)
    UVC.JavaEdit("PSW").SetSecure "5256833195fsdqsdsqd447e4beefsdsdqd"
    wait(5)
    UVC.JavaButton("Connect").Click
Else
    print "Console is not present"
End If
```

It's strange as QTP is identifying my password field properly. When running the following code I get a value back as expected:

```
MsgBox Main.JavaEdit("password").GetROProperty("attached_text")
```

I have also tried to set the password without encrypting it but it's also not working.

PS: the same script was working before and has since stopped working for an unknown reason!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get when calling SetSecure? Or is there no error, and the value just not set? Also, the fact that you have Wait statements in there suggests something in the app is updating after you set the username - is this the case?

Comment: I am not getting any error for SetSecure, the step is executed but I can see that the password is not set.I have added wait statement just for debugging but there is no event to wait for.

Comment: Get the return value from SetSecure, see if it's returning an error code. Also check if Err.Number or Err.Description hsa been populated immediately after.

Comment: the issue turned out to be related to the application itself where an error pop up is triggered for no reason.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, please add the "solution" as an answer, and accept it yourself so this (answered/solved) question does not pop up in the list of unanswered questions anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers but none of your suggestions worked, I have ended up using a basic turnaround :

```
UVC.JavaEdit("JTextField").Set"admin"
UVC.JavaEdit("PSW").Click 1,1
UVC.JavaEdit("PSW").SetSecure"52581237d889935df36ae78587773a641f40"
UVC.JavaButton("Connect").Click
wait (5)
While JavaDialog("Login Error").Exist 
JavaDialog("Login Error").JavaButton("Ok").click
UVC.JavaEdit("PSW").RefreshObject
UVC.JavaEdit("PSW").SetSecure"52581237d889935df36ae78587773a641f40"
UVC.JavaButton("Connect").Click
Wend
```

I really don't get it how could the same function work sometimes and sometimes not!!

Comment: I think it fails to work whenever there are focus changes among your app´s windows that are not realizied. This is the case whenever Windows makes the task bar buttons of the focus changing apps blink. In my experience, SetSecure depends upon the app window having the focus. Don't know why, though.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
UVC.JavaEdit("PSW").SetSecure "5256833195fsdqsdsqd447e4beefsdsdqd"
```

with

```
UVC.JavaEdit("PSW").Click 1,1
UVC.JavaEdit("PSW").SetSecure "5256833195fsdqsdsqd447e4beefsdsdqd"
```

and it will work even with replay mode = "event". If you want to beautify this, you can use a click in the middle of the field, like in:

```
With UVC.JavaEdit("PSW")
    .Click .GetROProperty ("width")\2, .GetROProperty ("height")\2
    .SetSecure "5256833195fsdqsdsqd447e4beefsdsdqd"
End With
```

It seems that most Java password fields must first be focussed to be `SetSecure`-able.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure.. check whether the field is enabled by testing .getroproperty("editable").

Use any of these methods to set text in Java Edit field.

1. You could use JavaEdit("PSW").Object.Settext method - this uses the JTextField in JavaSwing object properties
2. You could use setfocus method before entering the string in the field
3. Get the position of the test field

x = JavaEdit("PSW").Getroproperty("abs_x")
y = JavaEdit("PSW").Getroproperty("abs_y")
Set DRP = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")
DRP.MouseClick x,y,"0"
DRP.SendString "the string"

1. You could also use JavaEdit's type object

Any of these methods should work for you. If not tough luck.. :)